# Shell input as variable

Tags: c++, input, parameters

I currently have a c++ Linux program that reads a parameter "P" from a file and loads it in RAM for further operations. The file has the following line :

```
P = 123
```

I would like the program to take P from shell input instead of the file. I am open to all options, as long as I can manually enter P while connected in SSH.
What I have in mind is something like an input prompt :

```
sudo myprogram start
enter P value : (I would manually enter "123" here)
```

Or maybe an argument :

```
sudo myprogram start 123
```

It must be simple to do but I do not know how, so any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: `myprogram` is your C++ executable?

Comment: @KingsIndian : Yes  -----  bobbogo : Could you please add details ? I am not sure to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the only data that the file has then the file operation is needless. 
Simply pass 123 (or whatever) to your C++ program and convert the string into integer.

Assuming you pass the integer as the second argument then:

```
int  p = atoi(argv[2]);
```

A better option is to use strtol:

```
char *s, *ptr;

s = argv[1];
int p = strtol(s, &ptr, 10);
```

---

If you can't make changes to the C++ code then simply do:

```
echo "P = 123" > file && myprogram start
```

---

If your file has more content and you can't simply do *echo* then, replace the existing line with new value:

```
 sed -i "s/P = [0-9]*/P = 123/" file && myprogram start
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, once I call myprogram with "start" as first argument and "P" as second argument, the program can directly put P value into RAM and use it as if it was read from the file ?

Comment: The whole C++ executable is in RAM when you run it. What do you mean by *putting P into RAM*? If your C++ code uses that value then pass from command line and remove the file reading part.

Comment: Do I need a parameter parser library ?

Comment: No, simply modify the C++ code so as to receive one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First version (enter from keyboard):

```
echo -n "enter P value: "
read P
```

Second version (pass as shell script argument):

```
P=$1
```

Third version (learn bash/shell programming):

- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html)
- [BASH Programming - Introduction HOW-TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)
- [and many others](http://www.google.de/search?q=bash+tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

This is basic C++. Take a look at the sample code below or visit the [site](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/13355/) I copied it from.

```
#include <iostream>

// When passing char arrays as parameters they must be pointers
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 5) { // Check the value of argc. If not enough parameters have been passed, inform user and exit.
        std::cout << "Usage is -in <infile> -out <outdir>\n"; // Inform the user of how to use the program
        std::cin.get();
        exit(0);
    } else { // if we got enough parameters...
        char* myFile, myPath, myOutPath;
        std::cout << argv[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) { /* We will iterate over argv[] to get the parameters stored inside.
                                          * Note that we're starting on 1 because we don't need to know the 
                                          * path of the program, which is stored in argv[0] */
            if (i + 1 != argc) // Check that we haven't finished parsing already
                if (argv[i] == "-f") {
                    // We know the next argument *should* be the filename:
                    myFile = argv[i + 1];
                } else if (argv[i] == "-p") {
                    myPath = argv[i + 1];
                } else if (argv[i] == "-o") {
                    myOutPath = argv[i + 1];
                } else {
                    std::cout << "Not enough or invalid arguments, please try again.\n";
                    Sleep(2000); 
                    exit(0);
            }
            std::cout << argv[i] << " ";
        }
        //... some more code
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you simply want to be prompted, within your C++ program, to input the value?
If that is what you want, this simple code will do the job:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int p = 0;
  std::cout << "Enter P value: ";
  std::cin >> p;
  std::cout << "Entered value: " << p << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ IOStreams aren’t particularly well-suited for interactive prompts like this. Better to read the value from the command line or from standard input, but without prompt.